# Why is this directive not working?

Tags: angularjs

I'm following a directive example but it's not working. I tried adding own version of JQuery. Doesn't work. For me it looks ok but since I'm beginning, this doesn't say a lot. Any idea?

http://plnkr.co/edit/1X1Yns10mzRrWmIfSRhV?p=preview

Embedded question: I think Angular is supressing default error handling in the directive, if I change for example element into esssslement - don't get errors in the console. Any way to change this?

Here again the directive's code:

```
myApp.directive('userStory', function() {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.mouseover(function() {
        console.log("mouseover!");
        element.css({'opacity': 0.1});
      }).mouseout(function() {
        element.css({'opacity': 1.0});
      });
  };

  var controller = function($scope) {

  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: controller,
    linker: linker
  };
});
```

Thanks!

Edit: Script in plnkr is corrected - 1. key has to be "link" not "linker", 2. JQuery script has to be included, and before Angular include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

First, the `link` function  is `link` and not `linker`. On the other hand, to bind "classic" events in angular, you use this syntax:

```
element.bind('event', function() {

   //stuff

});
```

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WX8Pcm6ZVwA9F00Ry8Mz?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thank you. The "linker" was a typo from my side. `element.mouseover` is in a (early edition) book though -  probably a mistake from them?

Comment: Maybe, But I never saw that. Otoh, if you want to use jquery, include it always before Angular.

Comment: don't have to use `bind` if jQuery is loaded since `angular.element` then uses full jQuery API. Don't see anything wrong with `linker` either...is valid declared function name

Comment: @charlietfl but `element.mouseover` is not working. You can take a look in my plunkr. The "linker" issue was that I was using it also as key.

Comment: @lxx understood...example code likely came from an example that did have jQuery loaded in page

Comment: @charlietfl you're right - the point was to include jQuery before Angular, as Jesus suggested. - then it works with `element.mouseover`